# global pub-sub/event-handling in ractive

Tags: ractivejs

I'm trying to determine the best way to establish cross-component-communication. My first thought was to use `ractive.fire` with a wildcard, but that doesn't seem to work. Am I trying to mis-use ractive.fire? What would be the suggested way for doing cross-component-communication with ractive?

```js
Ractive.components.pubSub = Ractive.extend({ 
    oninit() {
        this.on('*.customEvent', () => alert('pub sub got your custom event!'))
    }
})
Ractive.components.something = Ractive.extend({ 
    template: '#something'
})
let ractive = new Ractive({
    target: 'body',
    template: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ractive@0.10.3/ractive.js"></script>
<script id="app" type="text/ractive">
    <pubSub />
    <something />
</script>
<script id="something" type="text/ractive">
    <button on-click="@.fire('customEvent')">Fire Custom Event</button>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ractive doesn't prescribe a convention for data sharing/cross-component communication. However, it does give you the facilities to do it. A common practice I've seen is to create a "dummy instance" and use its `ractive.fire()` and `ractive.on()` methods.

```
// The dummy instance, make it visible to components.
const pubsub = Ractive()

const SourceComponent = Ractive.extend({
  template: '<button click="send()">Click me</button>',
  send(){
    pubsub.fire('message')
  }
})

const ListeningComponent = Ractive.extend({
  onInit(){
    pubsub.on('message', () => {
      console.log('called')
    })
  }
})
```

Alternatively, if all you want is to share state across all components, modify them anywhere you want, and have everyone re-render on change, you can put that state in [`@shared`](https://ractive.js.org/api/#shared).

Comment: Thanks for the info! I don't know how I missed @shared in the docs. That sounds like it might be exactly what I'm looking for. Sounds similar to svelte's store concept, which I like (https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/store.js). I should have plenty to go on now.